# XCode: SQLite3: Leaving connection open

Tags: ios, sqlite

I am writing an iPhone app that makes many calls to a sqlite database. My question is, is it best to leave open and close the database connection for every query, or to leave it open and just close it when the app closes.

There are times in my app where I may loop through many iterations and in each I am adding a row to the db, but as I have it now, for each iteration I open the db, perform the operation, then close the db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would leave it open all the time the app is in the foreground and only close it when it goes into the background or when I get a memory warning. It might be expensive to open the connection, so I like to do it as little as possible, however it might consume resources which could be better used elsewhere.

You need to write all your db access code to open the connection if it's not already open; so you can close it whenever you like.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, if you are making lots of calls to update the database, then I would try and keep it open.  If there are 'chunks' of logic that you can keep the db open for then that would good, maybe having it open for all the time the app is running might not be the best thing - but this is really dependent on the architecture of your app.